# What exactly means Concurrency in Apache Bench?

Tags: benchmarking, apachebench

I use Apache Bench for test some applications performance. I try to send 10 requests with concurrency = 3. I understand that concurrency 3 means that Apache Bench opens 3 TCP connections with my application. For example:

I suppose that I have 3 TCP connections with 3 requests `[1,2,3]`.
Apache Bench first sends request `1`. So my new requests will be [4,2,3].

Next Step:

1. Will Apache Bench wait until get a response from request `1` and after send request `2`? 
   I mean that the flow of requests will be: `1` ->`response1`->`2`->`response2` ...... ?

OR

2. Will Apache Bench send request `2` without wait the response of `1`? 
   I mean that the flow of requests will be: `1`-> `2` -> `response for request 1` -> `3` ....

What really applies?

Comment: In his answer he says that `request 1` finishes. This mean that I get the response for `request 1` or just apache bench sends the request?

Comment: It will have 3 (or whatever you set the concurrency value as) connections open at any given time. No, it does not wait for the first response to send the next. It fires off 3 requests, and each time a response comes back for any given request, that request is replaced with the next one.